# How to use Rails wildcard syntax to match both index and show routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, glob

I want to use a rails wildcard route to match anything in the specific namespace. i.e. I want `GET /foo/bar` and `get /foo` to redirect to `/quz`. I can't seem to figure out how to get that to work in `routes.rb` though:

```
# this only captures requests to `/foo/bar`, not `/foo`
namespace :foo do 
  match '*path', to :quz 
end

# this only captures requests to `/foo`, not `/foo/bar`
namespace :foo do 
  match '/', to :quz 
end

# I've resorted to this, which looks ugly. 
namespace :foo do 
  match '*path', to :quz 
  match '/', to :quz 
end
```

Would love any advice! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set `*path` as argmuents optional by put it in `()`. Try this:

```
namespace :foo do 
  match '(*path)', to :quz, via: :get
end
```